# timer to jquery div with sliding

Tags: jquery, html

im using this code http://jsbin.com/uqovih/381/edit
and I need to know if there anyway to do timer sliding for it

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var $gal = $('#divslider'),
$sli = $('#divinslider'),
$box = $('div',$sli),
W    = $gal.width(), // 500
N    = $box.length,  // 3
C    = 0;            // a counter

$sli.width(W*N);


$('#prev, #next').click(function(){
    C = (this.id=='next' ? ++C : --C) <0 ? N-1 : C%N;
    $sli.start().animate({left: -C*W },800);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsbin.com/ODOmOQAN/1/edit

```
function slide(){
  C = ++C <0 ? N-1 : C%N;
  $sli.stop().animate({left: -C*W },800);
}

setInterval(slide,3000); // update the timer depending upon your need.
```